# Zabbix public key authorization in ssh agent discovery rule

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys, zabbix, service-discovery

I am using Zabbix 4.0.
Trying to make a discovery rule for another remote linux server with SSH agent.
It asks for privatekey file and public key file. I understand it asks for privatekey file.
I put the private key file for remote server into the zabbix server .ssh director.
But why does zabbix also wants us to enter public key file. Privatekey file should be enough
to connect to remote server.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably the public key of the server (aka *hostkey*), that is needed to verify that Zabbix is connecting to the legitimate server.

Comment: public key of which server ? zabbix server ? or remote server ?

Comment: The remote server.